# In the constructor of some component class, the 'this' holds the class itself instead of an instance

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular and am trying to contribute more components to the Angular project at work with my colleagues. Tried my best to follow the best practices so the only thing I made in the constructor of the components is storing the necessary data from the dependent services. However, my code behaves differently.

I'm sure that in the debugger all dependencies are working as expected, but the 'this' strangely refers to the component itself, instead of an instance of it.

```js
// the component
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SomeService } from '../some.service';
// and many other imports

@Component({
  selector: 'app-some-component',
  templateUrl: './some.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./some.component.sass']
})
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  someProperty: any;

  constructor(
    some: SomeService
    // and many other dependencies
  ) {
    this.someProperty = some.doSomethingQuick(); // <-- `this` refers to the ctor itself
    // binding, transforming the data from the dependencies
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}

// the service
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SomeService {

  constructor() { }

  doSomethingQuick() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

I've also debugged other good components and when it's created by `createView` it returns the instance but for my case, it returns the ctor itself. So frustrating. Can somebody explain what's exactly under the hood?

Comment: for any logic purpose, use lifecycle hooks (like ngOnInit) rather than the constructor (just use it for dependancy injection, like your SomeService).

Comment: Do you see the issue in the `ngOnInit` method, or only in the constructor? There aren't any calls to `this` in your sample code. What effect does the issue have on the running code?

Comment: How do you use your SomeComponent? 
Try transforming the data on nginit

Comment: @PatrickStephansen I can see it’s the instance I’m hoping for in the ngOnInit. Just want to know what’s under the hood.

Comment: The constructor is called before any of the Angular-specific lifecycle events including the data bindings for @Input and @Output properties. What specifically is different about `this` from what you expect?

Comment: @MiguelPinto primarily I’m creating UI containers with these components as the entry point for each feature in the routing modules.

Comment: @PatrickStephansen I may misunderstood the concept of constructor in Angular, that it should be fully constructed so it can be manipulated with the user-provided code there. Are you trying to say that it’s an expected behavior that `this` can refer to different things before the very first lifecycle hook?

Comment: `this` still refers to the instance of the component in the constructor, but any properties that are set by the Angular framework will not be set yet when it runs, which I think may have lead you to the conclusion that it was not a proper component instance. Constructors are a typescript feature, they aren't specific to  Angular.

Comment: @PatrickStephansen after the code hit the breakpoint in the constructor, in the console I can successfully run `let ins = new this()` and have `ins` an instance. It may be a problem with my debugger, I think

Comment: `new this()` should give you another instance in any constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities:

With `ngOnInit(){}` method:

```js
// the component
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SomeService } from '../some.service';
// and many other imports

@Component({
  selector: 'app-some-component',
  templateUrl: './some.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./some.component.sass']
})
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  someProperty: any;

  constructor(
    some: SomeService
    // and many other dependencies
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.someProperty = this.some.doSomethingQuick();
  }
}
```

or straight in the declaration:

```js
// the component
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SomeService } from '../some.service';
// and many other imports

@Component({
  selector: 'app-some-component',
  templateUrl: './some.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./some.component.sass']
})
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  someProperty = this.some.doSomethingQuick();

  constructor(
    some: SomeService
    // and many other dependencies
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```